# Perform ACTION_CALL intent immediately after the permission was requested and granted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-permissions

I am making an application that is supposed to dial a number after a button has been clicked on. All I want is to do is for the action to be performed immediately after the first permission request.

```
//everything here is in an onClickListener
//number is already specified
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", Uri.encode(number))));

if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            activity.startActivity(callIntent);
        }
        else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {//if Api >= 23
                if(activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)){
                    //WHY THIS PERMISSION IS NEEDED
                    final String why_the_permission_is_needed = "why it is needed";
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .setTitle("WHY THIS PERMISSION IS NEEDED")
                            .setMessage(why_the_permission_is_needed)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                            .create().show();
                }
            }

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, DIAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        
                activity.startActivity(callIntent);
            }

        }
```

What happens is that before

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, DIAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

is done the remaining code

```
 if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        
                activity.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
```

would have been executed. Meaning the user will have to click on the button once to get the permission and again to actually perform the intent, which is what I do not want.

Also

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, DIAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

returns void.

Answer (score 0):

You should override [`onRequestPermissionsResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D)) on your activity and handle the requested permission result. To be able to reinvoke your process, declare your click listener algorithm in a function and recall it when the result was ready:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        performCall();
    }
})
```

And then process the result:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull @NotNull String[] permissions, @NonNull @NotNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
        if (requestCode == DIAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            performCall();
        }
    }
}
```